# Is there a way for React Native to persist data even when app uninstalled?

Tags: android, ios, react-native

I was trying to do some fingerprinting on user's devices because we have a few functions that is to make sure that whatever transaction that user made, cannot be executed again. Plus we want to detect whether this user have used our app before prior to the app uninstall.

I have tried few methods to achieve this. MAC address is not available on iOS and using `getUniqueId()` from `react-native-device-info` library is not really I want because the unique ID will be removed when the app uninstalled. I have tried on caching values by using `react-native-webview` with `window.localStorage` `injectedJavascript()` but the key-value pairs that I've cached through the webview browser was removed too.

I hope there's idea or solution for this use case. I have been breaking my brains on doing this for awhile.

Comment: You can store a value in the keychain or possibly make use of the iOS device check framework

Comment: you could create a file using relevant info and save it on user's device

Comment: @Paulw11 I thought keychain will be removed when the app uninstalled?... DeviceCheck API starts with iOS 11, if only it is compatible with iOS 10, then it would be nice...

Comment: @nazmul Does the file stays on the phone upon uninstall?

Comment: No, keychain remains until the device is erased.  All files are removed when the app is uninstalled. DeviceCheck will survive a device erase since it is stored in Apple's servers.  iOS 11+ is 99% of devices.

Comment: if you save a file on any specific folder in users device, it stays there until the user delete it manually like any file in downloads folder. @Kaydarin

Comment: @nazmul that may be the case on Android but the OP is asking mainly about iOS. All of an apps files are removed when an iOS app is removed.

Comment: @Paulw11I read somewhere that DeviceCheck cannot be used to identify devices uniquely. I'm not sure about this, can you confirm if this is right?

Comment: @nazmul Owh okay, it's a solution, but if it's removable then it's going to be a little bit issue, but I can try it for now...

Comment: @Paulw11 it's okay for nazmul to provide that info, I am working on both platform actually so I can try it nonetheless...

Comment: Device check allows you to store two bits of information that are associated with a device.  What those bits mean is up to you. It doesn't let you identify a device as such, but you can set a bit that means "trial redeemed" and retrieve that bit later to see if that device has already had a trial

Comment: @Paulw11 Can the 'two-bits' information removed / refreshed by the user?

Comment: No. They are linked to the device and your app's secret key. Only your server using the opaque identifier from the device and the secret key can change the bits

Answer (score 1):

maybe you can try this:https://github.com/oblador/react-native-keychain
it will store data in your keychain. so even if you uninstall you app. it will  persist data in the iCloud or the phone.

Comment: I don't think it has anything to do with the iCloud. It will stay on the phone even if you are not using iClound for Keychain. Removing an app doesn't delete keychain entries of that app

Comment: I can't find in the library's documentation stated that whatever stored there will still persist even on app removal or maybe I have missed something

Answer (score -1):

Sqlite database persist after uninstalling. Maybe you can explore this path. https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-sqlite-storage.